# getResourceAsStream to get a file inside the war

Tags: java, maven, jboss

I have a maven project that builds a war file with a file inside it I want to read.

No exceptions are thrown...

***EDIT*** Note that this is **not in a servlet**:

```
@Path("")
@Stateless
public class MessageRestService {

//String liquibaseTenantDefinitionFile = "/WEB-INF/liquibase/db.tenant.xml";
//String liquibaseTenantDefinitionFile = "/WEB-INF/classes/liquibase/db.tenant.xml";
//String liquibaseTenantDefinitionFile = "WEB-INF/classes/liquibase/db.tenant.xml";
//String liquibaseTenantDefinitionFile = "/liquibase/db.tenant.xml";
String liquibaseTenantDefinitionFile = "liquibase/db.tenant.xml";

public InputStream getTenantFile(){
    try {
        return getClass().getClassLoader()
                .getResourceAsStream(liquibaseTenantDefinitionFile);
    } catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println(e);
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

This file does exist in the war file:

```
jar -tf target/grest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war | grep db.tenant.xml
WEB-INF/classes/liquibase/db.tenant.xml
```

The method *always* returns null, I've tried all kinds of permutations:

- leading slashes
- no leading slashes
- different classloader getting methods
- WEB-INF/ no WEB-INF
- with and without classes

I cannot figure out how to do this.  I'm using wildfly and testing with the Arquillian jboss container.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://haveacafe.wordpress.com/2008/10/19/how-to-read-a-file-from-jar-and-war-files-java-and-webapp-archive/

Comment: It's not a servlet, see my edit

Comment: Is `MessageRestService class` placed under `WEB-INF/classes` or  a jar file under `WEB-INF/lib`?

Comment: The former, a class in WEB-INF/classes

Answer (score 1):

Spot the difference:

```
"/WEB-INF/liquibase/db.tenant.xml";
```

and

```
/WEB-INF/classes/liquibase/db.tenant.xml
```

but actually they are both wrong. It should be:

```
/liquibase/db.tenant.xml
```

as the CLASSPATH starts at /WEB-INF/classes.

Comment: No luck with that, you can see from my edit what I've tried

Comment: I can see from your edit what you *think* you've tried. Not the same thing. The only thing we can actually trust I s your code, and it's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The root of your war file is not in your webapp class loader. The `WEB-INF/classes` directory is in your webapp class loader. You should move the resources to there, and then just use paths rooted at WEB-INF/classes.

Comment: The resource is in `WEB-INF/classes/liquibase/db.tenant.xml` inside the war, I'm not sure what you mean.